# MySQL Foreign Key - Cannot Resolve Table Name Close TO

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys

I've run into a foreign key issue that really has me stumped. The specific error I get when running my migration is:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `products` add constraint products_provider_id_foreign foreign k
>     ey (`provider_id`) references `id` (`providers`) on delete cascade)

The MySQL `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` result under **Latest Foreign Key Error** is:

> 2016-02-22 21:38:17 11debc000 Error in foreign key constraint of table testdb/#sql-186_18db:
>    foreign key (`provider_id`) references `id` (`providers`) on delete cascade:
>   Cannot resolve table name close to:
>    (`providers`) on delete cascade

I've checked all of the following:

- Same data type: `int`
- Same data length: `10`
- Same signing: `unsigned`
- The target table is a key: `primary`
- Both tables correct engine: `INNODB`
- Both tables same charset: `utf8`
- Both tables same collation: `utf8`

The first table is `providers` and has a primary key **id** defined as `INT(10)` and unsigned:

[image: Providers Table]

The second table is `products` and has a column called `provider_id` defined as `INT(10)` and unsigned.

[image: Products Table]

This error is of course well documented, especially on SO, but none of the common things ([including this checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131421/foreign-key-add-fails-in-mysql-with-error-code-1005-number-150)) are working. Does anyone see anything wrong here or have any other suggestions?

For what it is worth, my system:

- OSX 10.8.5
- MySQL 5.6.11
- Migrations are in Laravel 5.2 (doubt this is related to the issue though)

### **EDIT**

The relevant portion of the Laravel migration to add the foreign key is:

```
Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('provider_id')->references('providers')->on('id')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('brands')->on('id')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

The creation of the products table starts like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('provider_id')->unsigned();
```

And the relevant part of the providers migration is:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('providers', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
```

I originally had the foreign key part of the table creation with `Schema::create(...)` but when it wasn't working, I tried making it come *after* the creation in case for some reason it wasn't building the migration correctly.

Comment: Could you post your migrations for product and providers also?

Comment: The syntax is a little backward. It needs to be `REFERENCES table (column)` but you have `REFERENCES column (table)`. Should be `REFERENCES providers (id)`. Did Laravel create that syntax?

Comment: @JeremyHarris: Did you add `$table->integer('provider_id')->unsinged();`  and `$table->integer('brand_id')->unsigned();` in your migration?

Comment: @JilsonThomas I added the relevant snippets of the migration code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('provider_id')->references('providers')->on('id')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('brands')->on('id')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

to

```
Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('provider_id')->references('id')->on('providers')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

You've swapped the position for column name and table.

Comment: Hah. That should be my cue to give it up for the night. Thanks for spotting that!

Comment: Unbelievable. This problem has been haunting me for the past few hours and I think I have checked all my table properties a zillion times. This is so easy to overlook, and I'm glad I found this!