# Cannot add foreign key constraint - Cannot resolve table name close to error

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have an error while trying to create a foreign key constraint in my MySQL Database.

NOTE: my problem may seem very similar to: [MySQL Foreign Key - Cannot Resolve Table Name Close TO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568053/mysql-foreign-key-cannot-resolve-table-name-close-to) . However, the solution to this question DOES NOT fit for my question, because my table name and column name are not swapped.

**MySQL version**: 5.7

I have a table, called `gds`:

```
DESCRIBE gds;
+--------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created_at         | timestamp            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at         | timestamp            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name               | varchar(255)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| logo               | varchar(255)         | NO   |     |         |                |
+--------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I created a new table, called `super_valuations`:

```
DESCRIBE super_valuations;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created_at   | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at   | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| gds_id       | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name         | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now, I want to create a foreign key between `super_valuations.gds_id` and `gds.id`.

I tried the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE `super_valuations` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `super_valuations_gds_id_foreign` 
FOREIGN KEY (`gds_id`) 
REFERENCES `gds` ( `id` );
```

That results in an error:

> ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

I tried running `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`, and the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section returns:

> LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
>
> 2019-06-10 10:02:53 0x7f93a0564700 Error in foreign key constraint of table dbname/#sql-1_401:
>   FOREIGN KEY (`gds_id`) REFERENCES `gds` ( `id` ):
>   Cannot resolve table name close to:
>   ( `id` )

I honestly can't understand the problem. The table `gds` **exists** (I can run `select * from gds`). Is there a syntax problem in my command?

Comment: There must be something else you are not telling, since it works well in MySQL 5.7. See the fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hmPTUNKFedmtV9KouYCF4E/0  Are you sure you have privileges?

Comment: What is the table type of the gds table? FKs are only supported by innodb. If gds is an innodb table, then is it partitioned? Partitioned tables do not support FKS.

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm executing the command as root

Comment: @Shadow you got the right clue. The gds table is the only one using MyISAM instead of InnoDB,  I can't understand why. Thank you!